# How to package OSGi subsystems with bndtools

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools, subsystem

I am evaluating bndtools as an alternative to the websphere OSGi tooling in eclipse, to package liberty profile features.

Liberty profile uses OSGi subsystems packed as a .esa for extensions to the runtime. It appears that it is possible to package a subsystem using BND, based on this file in the bnd git repo.

https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bndlib/src/aQute/bnd/exporter/subsystem/SubsystemExporter.java

But I can't find any documentation about how to setup an ESA project. Can someone give me some pointers?